# Mac OS command line authenticating with GitHub

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, cocoapods

While trying to connect to GitHub to validate my podspec, I keep getting the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myAccount/myRepo.git/': Failed to connect to 159.82.13.140 port 80: Operation timed out

It seems to be my connection to GitHub specifically, because cloning from the command line throws the same error:

```
git clone https://github.com/myAccount/myRepo.git ~/Desktop/testClone
Cloning into '/Users/myAccount/Desktop/project'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myAccount/myRepo.git/': Failed to connect to 159.82.13.140 port 80: Operation timed out
```

Normally I manage VCS through Xcode, which lets me input my auth credentials, but I realized I need to setup ssh keys.

After setting that up, it looks like it should work:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi myAccount! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

However the error persists both when trying to run `pod spec lint` and `git clone`. I've restarted my terminal shells, and as a Mac user (Mojave) I learned that I need to create a file at `~/.ssh/config` with the below text:

```
Host github.com
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**Any idea on next steps?**

I'm not seeing the key in my KeyChain Access. Shouldn't it be there? If so, how do I import it?

**UPDATE:**

Tried using [this article](https://medium.com/@ginnyfahs/github-error-authentication-failed-from-command-line-3a545bfd0ca8) to connect with a generated token; but still get the same error. Also updated my config with these fields, which may not be getting pointed to or something...

```
Host github.com   
User git
Hostname github.com
PreferredAuthentications ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Port 80
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Up until I attempted to use the generated token, I was able to successfully ssh in with `ssh -T git@github.com` but now I get the following error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Somehow I made it worse? Tried reseting with the following command:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

And also removed my ~/.ssh directory, but not getting prompted for a password and still getting the timeout failure.

Although I can succeed with a direct connection again:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256.*******
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi ******! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

**Anyone have anyway I can reset this and try to start over? Or any idea why I can authenticate with ssh -T but can't clone?**

Confirmed I can still access through Xcode. Downloaded Github Desktop and authenticated because I read that would help. Still not getting prompted for a password.

```
brew install hub
```

This prompted me for a password, but still timed out!!!!

Comment: Make sure it's not a spurious connectivity issue. GitHub had issues earlier today - https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Just checked again, and the issue still persists :( Also, if the servers were down or I had an environmental problem / firewall blocking me I think `ssh -T git@github.com` should've failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/myAccount/myRepo.git ~/Desktop/testClone
> ```

As long as you are using `https://...`, you can tweak your SSH configuration all day long... it will be ignored.

Try using first an *SSH* URL: `git clone git@github.com:myAccount/myRepo.git`, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: OMG!!! Of course. That explains why I could ssh, but pod spec lint needs to HTTP...